# Como puedo corregir el siguiente error en JAVA

Tags: java, java-swing, java-ee, javafx, java-8

Espero no molestarlo,

Les comento que estoy realizando un servicio REST con JSON, pero por alguna razón me sale este error y ya he empleado tiempo tratando de resolverlo. Espero y me puedan ayudar.

**The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las imagenes son dificiles de ver. y que dice el log del servidor? y el codigo?

Comment: Este es el mensaje que me expone,  con el error 1072 del archivo build.xml, The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.
**Solo debe de dar click a la imagen para expandirla**

Comment: No. Las imagenes no se ven bien en celulares y otros dispositivos, por eso no se recomienda subirlas. Mira por favor [ask] y de paso hace el [tour]. y que dice el log del servidor, donde hay mas detalles?

Comment: Si es un servicio REST con JSON, ¿Porque pusiste etiquetas de swing y javafx?